# Move UIView in specific area

Tags: ios, objective-c, touch-event

I use the following code to move an UIImageView

```
    - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
    paddle.center = CGPointMake(location.x, paddle.center.y);
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

It works great, moving from left to right. But i can't figure out how to avoid moving over the screen, i meant to move it but don't intersect right and left edges of my screen. let's say 10 pixels from left and 10 from right.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are the one saying this:

```
paddle.center = CGPointMake(location.x, paddle.center.y);
```

So where `paddle` is, is entirely up to you. If you don't want it at a certain x value, don't set it to that x value.

Second, never never call `touchesBegan` from within `touchesMoved`.

Third, you'd be much happier and safer using a UIPanGestureRecognizer. Situations like this are exactly what it's for.

Comment: And in fact I happen to have code right here for a view that can be moved only horizontally: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch05p203gestureRecognizers/ch18p541gestureRecognizers/HorizVertPanGestureRecognizers.swift